# Automatic merging of files in Linux (One way)

Tags: linux, merge

I'm looking for a linux command line utility, that can auto-merge
differences between two files(one way only).

For all diffs present only in source file, the tool should apply
those automatically to destination.
If there is a conflict, the tool should skip it for manual resolution.

P.S.
1. This has to be done over 100s of files, that's why GUI tool is not suitable.
2. Source code control tools can't be used, otherwise I would have used 'p4 resolve'
3. I looked at 'sdiff -o', but it is interactive

Example:

### dest file

B
C
D

### src file

A
B
C
E

### After merge, dest file should be

A <-- auto merged
B
C
D <-- left for manual resolution

Comment: Not sure if this might help:  http://www.linuxtutorialblog.com/post/introduction-using-diff-and-patch-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Are these files in source control? Source control can manage diffs this way because they have engines that build files from a series of deltas. When you merge files there are well-defined ways to walk delta trees based on timestamp or hash-entry order and assemble the final file.

If you are using source control just use their merge facilities. If you just have two files with similiar content then there is no sensible way to accomplish this. How could a program understand how you want the files merged?

To be succinct,A merge requires three parties the first file, the second file, and a common ancestor.

Comment: I have been following your edits. And finally, a +1 for saying "A merge requires three parties the first file, the second file, and a common ancestor."

Comment: I already mentioned that i could have used p4 resolve if it was possible.
The reason there is no common parent, is because the files belong to 
3rd party codebase. Once we bring those into our srctree, we also make changes according to our needs.
And from time to time, we need to pick new versions of 3rd party codebase.
So if you think about it, for the same file, there are 3 revisions:
1. original 3rd party file
2. our additions (in our source tree)
3. new changes available in 3rd party codebase.

Comment: @nsfyn55: diff -u takes only 2 files, and it shows, what lines are conflicting, and what lines are added/removed in only one file.
So, this tool knows during diff, that a particular diff is present in srcfile only.

Comment: well at least the type of merge you are talking about